# How to find channel by name DiscordJS 12

Tags: javascript, discord

I know they changed some things and I've been very slowly attempting to grasp these changes, but something is escaping me and it's breaking other functions as well. So the simplest way I can solve this is by solving one of the simpler commands that are broken, which is a !sayto command that used to send a message to a specified channel by name. You could do for example `!sayto testing Hello! This is a test!` and it would say "Hello! This is a test!" in #testing. Now this doesn't work and I can't for the life of me find a method for accomplishing this anymore. I'll provide my code below, and hopefully someone can help me make sense of this.

```
let saytochan = bot.channels.cache.get(args[0]);
message.delete().catch();
    saytochan.send(botmessage);
```

It's important to me to be able to specify a channel by name when using the command. My only fear is that I'll end up having to define a variable for every channel by ID and handling it the hard way with ten million IF statements...
Appreciate any and all assistance with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use find channel

```
const ch = bot.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === `${args[0]}`);
```

then

```
ch.send(botmessage)
```

if the channel doesnt exist...

```
if (!ch) return message.channel.send("channel doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Thank you! I used to use a find function, but when it broke I went through so many iterations of botched code to end up with what I had posted above. I'll admit I don't understand the "c => c.name" part, but I applied it to my code in my own way and it still worked. Clearly I've got some more research to do so I can understand this better.

Comment: No problem! c just means channel. But yea it quite easy, I would recommend asking in the Discord.js server for simply questions like this as well. https://discord.gg/bRCvFy9